# How can I find the location of files installed via Software Center are available?

Tags: paths, installed-programs

I would like to know where I can find the location of program files of programs installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

For the programs installed system wide `whereis` command helps

```
whereis vim
```

But I like to use `which` command.

e.g. `which vim` shows the location of vim which'll be used, if you tried to run vim command on terminal. Also `whereis` command won't show the location of command if its in your home directory. For example. if your `~/bin` directory has a command `pqr` whereis won't show the location of `pqr`. `which pqr` shows its location too.

If you have set the aliases for the commands, for example if your terminal understands the shortcut `c` for `clear` command for example, you can get the original command, by typing the command:

```
type c
```

It will output:

> c is aliased to clear

Answer (score 2):

In terminal try using [whereis](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/whereis.1.html)

```
whereis <name of the program>
```

It will give the locations of program path.

e.g

```
whereis apt
apt: /etc/apt /usr/lib/apt /usr/share/apt /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you shouldn't *need* to know the location of programs, because if you need to run them from the command-line then they'll be on your path anyway, and if you run them from within the GUI, or within another application, they'll be set up in there by their installation script.

But if you are curious, most executables will be placed into `/usr/bin`

(Or at least a symbolic link from there will exist to the executable.)

There are exceptions.  There will be some system-related ones that are available from `/bin` instead, and some system-related ones only intended for superuser access (ie, for use with sudo) in `/sbin`.

The `which` command can be used to find out exactly where an application is (if you run it by typing its name on the command-line).  You use it like `which <command>` where command is replaced with the command you'd type.  For example:

```
which apt-get
```

Tells you: `/usr/bin/apt-get`.  As I said above, most executables are placed in `/usr/bin` ;)

If you type the following

```
ls /usr/bin -l
```

Then it will show you all the files in `/usr/bin`.  You'll then notice that some of them are actually symbolic links to elsewhere.

Now, `/usr/bin` will only contain the executable file.  All of its support files will be in different locations (usually within `/usr`).  For example, library files it requires will be in `/usr/lib`, and non-executable data files it needs will be in `/usr/share`.  It may also store configuration or state information in `/var/lib`, or in users' home directories.

Answer (score 2):

Other than on Windows, on Linux systems an application is (usually -- there are few exceptions) not tried to be installed into "one place" (no such thing like `C:\Program Files\AppName` holding almost all the applications files).

Instead there are dedicated places where to put executables (what you call from the command line or via your graphical interface's menu), another for libraries used by applications (so multiple applications can share the same library and automatically profit from its updates), configuration files, documentation, and so on.

As already pointed out, you can use the `which` command to tell you the executable used, and there is the `whereis` command. A third command coming in handy is `locate`, which would list up all files in the system having the specified string in their `/path/to/filename`, plus the powerful `find` command.

You can get more information about each of them reading their [Man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) -- e.g. `man find` would tell you how to use the `find` command.